# Where is the synergy configuration file?

Tags: synergy

I downloaded the latest deb of synergy from the synergy website.

When I run it I get an installer and get the option to enable the password etc.

However, now I want to reset the password but I can't find the configuration.

Where does synergy store it's configuration?  there is no /etc/synergy.conf or any synergy.conf file anywhere.

Comment: run `locate synergy.conf` command.

Comment: ~/.quicksynergy/synergy.conf maybe?

Comment: haha... I found it.  /tmp/qt_temp.TJ8723

Comment: Kinda dumb because you loose the config when the machine reboots.  So it would be a good idea to copy the file to /etc and recofigure it to run from the copy

Answer (score 3):

You will find the synergy configuration file in the Directory
  `$HOME/.config/Synergy/Synergy.conf`

In this configuration file there is an option crypto Pass

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the file appears to be located at `~/.synergy.conf`. You can also tell which configuration file it loads if you run `./synergys -d DEBUG`